# Replacing whole string with part of it using Regex in Python Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, regexp-replace

I have a table in pdf found on this link: https://taxation-customs.ec.europa.eu/system/files/2022-11/tobacco_products_releases-consumption.pdf
I am trying to clean the data before doing analysis but I noticed that between 2014-2017 the cigarette data was merged due to error. Instead of two cells per year in a column for Sweden and UK I got one merged which looks something like this: 5393688\r28587000

I would like to update data only for Sweden and get the first value before \r.

So far my code was as follows:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
cig= pd.DataFrame(tabula.read_pdf(r"https://taxation-customs.ec.europa.eu/system/files/2022-11/tobacco_products_releases-consumption.pdf", pages ='all')[0])
cig.replace(to_replace='N/A', value=0, inplace=True, regex=True)
cig= cig.replace(',','', regex=True)
```

After this I tried

```
df.iloc[26,:].str.replace("('\r').*","")
cig.iloc[26,:] = cig.iloc[26,:].replace("('\r').*","", regex=True)    
and
cig.iloc[26,:].replace(to_replace='(?:[0-9]+)([^0-9]{2})([0-9]+)', value='', regex=True)
```

But none of the above seem to produce desired result and I still have values with similar format i.e. 5393688\r28587000

Answer (score 0):

Set `regex=True` and assign the changed subset  back to the dataframe:

```
df.iloc[26,:] = df.iloc[26,:].replace("('\r').*","", regex=True)
```

Comment: Hello Ali, thank you for the contribution but this did not help. In the mean time I tried cig.iloc[26,:].replace(to_replace='(?:[0-9]+)([^0-9]{2})([0-9]+)', value='', regex=True, inplace=True) but this didn't help either

Comment: Hello! Good try. Update your question. Provide some reproducible code and data. And I'll see where it is wrong. Also remember that when asking a question, providing images as data causes the contributors trouble because it makes it harder to reproduce the problem. And it often invites downvotes.